# Views sorting criteria with symbols

Tags: 8, views

Is there a possibility to change the sorting options ascending and descending by symbols in views to visitors?
I can change the words "Asc" and "Desc" in the settings of the view.

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

Comment: I've only ever been able to do this by implementing my own Twig overrides and or form alter to handle this. An advanced method would be offloading it to Javascript for sorting filters / submission.

Comment: I added 2 examples.

Comment: Yeah the easiest way IMO is to put the markup for sorting into templates and triggering form submits via javascript to apply it. But thats me.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the feedback. I'll give it a try.